# Send message to special client in network

Tags: android, sockets

I want send message to network with android.
How can i send message to one of the client on network with socket programming in android?

I search about socket programming and find it:

```
            ServerSocket SVsocket=null;

        try {

            SVsocket=new ServerSocket(8080);

            Socket s=SVsocket.accept();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));

            String incomingMsg = in.readLine() + System.getProperty("line.separator");


            String outgoingMsg = "goodbye from port " + "8080" + System.getProperty("line.separator");
            out.write(outgoingMsg);
            out.flush();

            s.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I think it send for all of the client (listen to 8080 port),but I want send just one client with and ip address.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of socket programming you can use notification send messages to particular user in your network.Send that userid to server and server will send notification message to that particular user .

Comment: I have a server,all client connect(with username and password) to this(any client send own ip address) and client can get desired ip address for chat. but now i want know how can i send a message from server/client to another client with ip address